# Navigation controller in modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Currently, when a button is tapped, a UIModalPresentationSheet comes up. I'd like to add a navigation bar at the top of this when it slides up. I've tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work. Here's what i'm currently trying and it returns this error.

```
    AthleteAdd *addAthlete = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addAthlete"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addAthlete];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:addAthlete animated:YES];

    addAthlete.delegate = self;
    addAthlete.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
  //  UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addAthlete];
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But it pushes it up modally, and without the modalpresentationsheet form. How can I make it so the navigation controller is sized correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to change your code like this :

```
    AthleteAdd *addAthlete = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addAthlete"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addAthlete];

    addAthlete.delegate = self;
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;


    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Because here, you try to present `addAthlete` from itself. So you get this error.

Answer (score 4):

You should present navigationController in which you encased your addAthlete.

```
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting from current viewcontroller itself.

Try something like,

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
   [self.parentViewController presentViewController: navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```